# Android apps connect with database server

Tags: android

I am trying to learn to implement android apps to get news, promotion message, and calendar from server. What is the best and easy way to communicate with database server? using JDBC or other methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Using JDBC?:

In the words of ***Commonsware***:

> Never never never use a database driver across an Internet connection,
>   for any database, for any platform, for any client, anywhere. That
>   goes double for mobile. Database drivers are designed for LAN
>   operations and are not designed for flaky/intermittent connections or
>   high latency.

On the **client side** (Android app), you can use SQLite to store data locally. It might not be necessary at all actually. For instance, it can be used for offline features, search, etc. For client-side, read up on this [simple post](http://osamashabrez.com/simple-client-server-communication-in-android/)

On the **server side** (whatever server side technology you know or want to learn), you can use whatever language, whatever database on whatever server OS you want. This part is commonly called the back-end, which will store your data while your app communicate with it through HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use json to parse data between server and the android device. In the server you can use jdbc with json  if you are using servlets in the server.

Answer (score 1):

To communicate between a server and an **android device** you can use ***JASON***. See following links for some help.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-asynctask-json-parsing-example.html

https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-json-parsing-url-example.html

Also in the device to deal with data within the device you can use SQLite. And in the server you can use jdbc if you are using servelets.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with Database server You should use web service  API such REST , soap